# »Auf« oder »an« dem Messestand?

Tags: preposition

> 1. Wir bedanken uns bei Ihnen für Ihren Besuch **an** unserem Messestand.
> 2. Wir bedanken uns bei Ihnen für Ihren Besuch **auf** unserem Messestand.

Bei der Recherche im Internet habe ich beide Versionen gefunden. Welche ist die Richtige? Oder haben sie unterschiedliche Bedeutungen?

Comment: An userem Messestand beschreibt die Situation eines kleinen Messestandes wo der Besucher auf dem Gang davor steht. Wenn bei einem grösseren Messestand der Besucher den Gang verlassen und den eigentlichen Messestand betreten hat passt auf unserem Messestand besser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beide Versionen sind richtig, und beide bedeuten grob dasselbe.

"Am" (an dem) Messestand hört sich mehr nach Thekenbedienung and und "auf" eher nach Tanzfläche, auf der man sich unterhalten hat, aber beide sollen ja nur aussagen, dass der Angeschriebene den Stand besucht hat - Wo er dabei genau bedient wurde, ist ja nicht relevant.

Answer (score 11):

Kommt drauf an. Ein Messestand kann eben einfach ein kleiner Stand sein, wie eine Theke, an der man mit Infomaterial bedient wird. Hier wäre meinem Gefühl nach "an" richtig.

Ein Messestand kann aber auch eine größere Fläche sein, auf der der Besucher herumlaufen und sich über die Produkte informieren kann. Hier würde ich "auf" benutzen.

Beispiel: auf der IAA hat ein Verlag einen kleinen Stand, wo er auf einem Tisch seine Zeitschriften auslegt und für Abos wirbt. "Auf dem Stand" fände ich hier ziemlich seltsam, denn es klingt, als wäre man auf den Tisch geklettert. Anderswo hat Renault mehrere hundert m² Fläche gemietet, auf der man herumlaufen und sich die Autos anschauen kann. Hier fände ich "an dem Stand" etwas komisch, denn es klingt für mich so, als hätte man den Stand nicht betreten, sondern wäre nur am Rand entlang gelaufen.

Comment: Man sagt _»auf der Messe«_, wenn man die gesamte Veranstaltung meint, und _»am Stand«_, wenn man einen Messestand meint. Ist der Stand aber so groß, dass schon er allein als eigene Veranstaltung gelten kann, klingt _»auf dem Stand«_ besser. Du hast also recht mit deiner Antwort.

Answer (score 3):

Für gewöhnlich gibt es auf einer Messe aufgebaute Einrichtungen von den Ausstellern, wie Buden, Theken, Tische etc., genannt Stände<sup>1</sup>, *an* denen man normalerweise steht. Es sei denn, man erklimmt diese Buden, Theken, Tische; dann stünde man *auf* ihnen. Folglich sollte der Aussteller für den Besuch *an* seinem Messestand und nicht *auf* seinem Messestand danken.

Allerdings könnte man *Stand* auch im Sinne von *Standfläche* verstehen. Dann stünde man *auf* dem Stand, wenn man eigentlich *auf* der Standfläche meint. Jedoch gibt es eigens für Stände auf Messen einen eigenen Eintrag im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Stand)<sup>1</sup>, bei dem Stände eben Einrichtungen oder Buden sind *an* denen man steht, und nicht die Flächen *auf* denen man steht.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Siehe Bedeutung 3. b) des Begriffs „Stand“, bereitgestellt durch das Digitale Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, https://www.dwds.de/wb/Stand#1, abgerufen am 20.09.2017.</sub>

Comment: Man ist aber "für eine Woche auf der Messe" und steht auch nicht oben auf der Messehalle. Sorry, das ist Quatsch.

Comment: Dein erster Satz behauptet, "auf" würde "obendrauf" bedeuten.

Comment: Wollen wir wirklich darüber streiten, was das Wort _auf_ bedeutet? http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auf_Praeposition#Bedeutung1a Manchmal weiß ich echt nicht, was Sie mit den Kommentaren bezwecken.